# JMeter + Maven: how to send test result data to InfluxDB?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance, maven, jmeter-maven-plugin

I use have JMeter tests run by [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin).

I’d like to send my test results data to InfluxDB (in order to visualize results in Grafana).

How can I do that? Do I need to set that in my POM file?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to amend anything in *pom.xml* file, the changes need to be introduced in JMeter Test Plan, to wit:

1. Add [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) to your Test Plan
2. Choose `org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.influxdb.InfluxdbBackendListenerClient` as the "Backend Listener Implementation"
3. Change `influxdbUrl` parameter to match your InfluxDB setup

   [image: JMeter InfluxDB Configuration]

That should be it, given you have InfluxDB up and running and Grafana dashboard created you will see real time metrics as your test goes.

More information: [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results - Part 2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

No need 
You need some configurations
Follow below document it works

[how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results)